# Как отправить словарь в функцию только со значениями True

Tags: python

есть следующие параметры

```
allow_merge = True
deny_delete = False
initialize = True
```

как отправить в функцию словарь `{имя_аргумента: значение}` только со значениями True у параметров?

на основе параметров выше вызов функции должен быть следующий:

```
connect.projects.create({'allow_merge': True,'initialize': True})
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, в функцию нужно отправить строку или булевые значения или вообще словарь, также у вас ошибки синтаксиса

Comment: разберитесь, пожалуйста, с кавычками в теле запроса.

Comment: @Ildar в принципе,я могу переделать параметры так,как они должны выглядеть в запросе. Это не принципиально. Поправил синтаксис. Т.е. если параметр в шапке принимает True,то добавить его в запрос. Если false,то нет

Comment: Строка — это `str` в питоне, у вас в коде словарь, так что непонятен всё ещё вопрос

Comment: добавьте сигнатуру функции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно с помощью генератора словарей собрать параметры только со значениями `True`

```
allow_merge = True
deny_delete = False
initialize = True

params = dict()
params['allow_merge'] = allow_merge
params['deny_delete'] = deny_delete
params['initialize'] = initialize
params = {name: value for name, value in params.items() if value}

print(params) # {'allow_merge': True, 'initialize': True}

connect.projects.create(params)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!